# What is the best way to create JSON from a hierarchical data from SQL Server database through C#.net?

Tags: c#, json, hierarchy

I have an SQL Table containing millions of data (hierarchical) like show below. I need to provide a Asp.net Web API for generating JSON for this, what would be the optimized way to do this.. ?  Getting the entire data in a single shot would be a time consuming sluggish operation.  Please advise.

ID      Name        ParentID

1      Parent      NULL

2      Parent1      NULL

3      Parent2      NULL

4      Parent3      NULL

5      Child1      1

6      Child2      5

7      Child3      6

8      Child4      6

9      Child5      6

10      Child6      6

Comment: I can't comment on speed, but I bet you could do this relatively easily with entity framework and json.net

Comment: Why would you want JSON with millions of records?

Comment: Yea, I agree with your suggestion ... but loading everything in a single shot wont be a scalable solution it seems :(

Comment: @Jedediah, my application deals with lot of data which would be  bound to a KendoUI grid

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kendo specifically, but I suspect that binding that many records to a grid (even if you don't display them all at once) would make your app incredibly laggy, if not crash entirely. You should probably look at an infinite scrolling or pagination solution, so that you're only loading a few records at a time from your database

Answer (score 1):

I would use a stored procedure to run the query, and feed that into your API controller. Then serialize it to JSON. That way SQL is handling the time consuming part, and your optimization will depend on that, then it can be fed into an object in your API controller, and serialized to JSON pretty easily.

Millions of rows is a lot though, and I would suggest using some form of filtering so that they can't get all of that at once.

Comment: I would agree on the millions of rows. If the data is being portrayed in a UI tree, try to use lazy loading and just get the children, one level down, of each clicked node...Start by loading the root and first level of children.